# Variable which is a database query doesnt render properly in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

My template doesnt render the key , values for the variable table which is a dictionary.

```
{% for key, value in table.items %}
<p> {{key}} : {{value}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The was how the variable 'table' was derived. Client is a model and Client_FirstName is the attribute of the model.

```
table = Client.objects.filter(Client_FirstName__startswith='p').values()
```

I am just trying to do a database query which i just learn  from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: did you try this in a shell ? was there any results returned ?

Answer (score 1):

There may not be any data in the database. Try this.

```
{% if table|length %}
    {% for key, value in table.items %}
        <p> {{ key }} : {{ value }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <div>There are no data in the database</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was rendering the database values wrongly on the template , this is how it should be done for a **list of dictionary**

```
    {% for x in table %}
     {% for key,values in x.items %}
     <p> {{key}} : {{values}} </p>
     {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```